# Lock the horizontal scroll in PHP/JQUERY

Tags: jquery, html, browser

I've constructed a little php/mssql WebApp for the use of my organisation.
It's run's on Android Tablets default browser.
this application is an interactive html Table how has a fixed width of 650px.
i dont want my users to be able to swipe there fingers and scroll the table horizontally.
(i need them to stay focused.)
i'll be glad to get some help.

Comment: But how will the user access/read the part of the table that is off-screen if they can't scroll horizontally? I think you are solving the wrong problem. Instead if creating a webpage that is too wide and then disabling horizontal scrolling, you should create a webpage that doesn't need to scroll horizontally in the first place.

Comment: NB: One more thing: You should learn a bit more about what the different web technologies are for (HTML, CSS, JavaScript, jQuery, PHP, etc.) because neither PHP nor jQuery has anything to do with whether a webpage scrolls horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

The overflow css property controls scrolling:

```
overflow:hidden;
```

or specifically:

```
overflow-x:hidden;
```